# Pass data back from Maui shell navigation

Tags: maui

The App navigates to a view in which the user selects an item on a CollectionView and then navigates back. How do I get the SelectedItem on the page that initiated the navigation?

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//SelectAnItem");
//Get the selected item
```

Comment: see the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0#pass-data

Comment: I don't know of a way for Shell to send data "back from" a page. Instead, use `MessagingCenter` Publish/Subscribe.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Shell navigation you can go back passing the selected element as a navigation param. I use a simple function:

```
public async static Task NavigateBackWithNavigationParameter(Dictionary<string, object> navParam)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..", navParam);
    }
```

In the viewmodel binded to the previous page in the navigation stack, adding the QueryProperty, it automatically sets the navigation parameter to the property in the class.

```
    [QueryProperty(nameof(NewClient), "NewClient")]
    public class MyBasePageViewModel : BaseViewModel

        private MyCustomClass _newClient;

        public MyCustomClass NewClient
        {
            get { return _newClient; }
            set { _newClient = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

Also I use this function to create the navigation parameter. Make sure that you type properly the parameter of sDestinationPropertyName.

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> GetNavigationParameter(string sDestinationPropertyName, object obj)
{            
     return new Dictionary<string, object> { { sDestinationPropertyName, obj } };
}
```

For me is working perfectly fine, even stacking various QueryProperties it works either passing one navigation parameter or the other.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

> The App navigates to a view in which the user selects an item on a
> CollectionView and then navigates back.

There are several ways to achieve this.

**Method 1**:A common approach is to use `EventHandler`.

You can define `EventHandler` in this view(Suppose the name is `SelectedPage`), just as follows:

```
 public static EventHandler<Item> mEventHandler; // define a static  EventHandler
```

After you select an item, you can pass the selected item with the following code:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<Item> handler = mEventHandler;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            Item item = new Item { Name= "Hello." };

            mEventHandler(this, item);
        }

        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
```

In the previous page, you can add the following code in the `constructor` of YourPreviousPage :

```
        SelectedPage.mEventHandler += delegate (object s, Item a)
        {
            BackCall(s, a);
        };
```

And the code of function `BackCall` is:

```
 private void BackCall(object send, Item a)
    {
        if (a == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(a));
        }
        else {

             DisplayAlert("Alert", "call back value is : " + a.Name, "OK");
        }
    }
```

**method 2**

You can also use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter?view=net-maui-7.0) to achieve this function.

Please refer to the following code:

```
public partial class PreviousPage: ContentPage 
{
    public PreviousPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // method 2

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<SelectedPage, Item>(this, "SelectedItem", (obj, item) =>
        {
            var newItem = item as Item;

            DisplayAlert("Alert", "call back value is : " + newItem.Name, "OK");

        });

    }
 }
```

SelectedPage.xaml.cs

```
  private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Item item = new Item { Name = "Hello." };

        MessagingCenter.Send(this, "SelectedItem", item);

        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
```